# Using an image as a link with a hover images

Tags: html, css

I'm using two images so that when you hover over the image it changes from an image with black  text to an image with red text, this part works fine but I have two instances of the image instead of just one - both are changing from black to red but this should only show once on the page. Can anyone please advise how to fix this?

```
<a href="mailto:admin@email.co.uk?Subject=contact" class="email" title="email    me">

.email {
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 730px;
height:60px;
display:block;
background: transparent url('images/email.png');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.email:hover {
background-image: url('images/email_hover.png');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by two instances of the image?  You mean you'd like to have only one image file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to implement this using only one image. So here is the solution.

**This is the image used as background.**

[image]

**This is the html page.**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.email {    
    width: 280px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    background:url('bg.png') no-repeat;
    /*extra styles */
    padding:10px;
    font-size:25px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}
.email:hover {
    background-position:0px -50px;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="mailto:admin@mail.co.uk?Subject=contact" class="email" title="email me">Email Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```